# How to copy my software to another computer?

Tags: 11.10, software-center

I have installed Ubuntu in my laptop and I want to copy all the software and games that I have downloaded from software center to my desktop such that I don't need to download them all over again. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Try  **[aptoncd [image: software_center_icon]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/aptoncd)** 
*Run the following to install the package via a terminal (Default keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)*

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install aptoncd
```

It makes a copy of all the packages on your system allowing you to install those packages on another system.

Just a side note, you could also copy all the deb files for the packages you have installed (as long as you haven't run `sudo apt-get clean` to clean the apt-get cache) from

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

Answer (score 3):

In the software centre, pick the `Sync Between Computers...` option from the `File` menu.

This will require that you create a software centre account.  If you've already created an Ubuntu single sign-on account (e.g. for Ubuntu One or Launchpad), you can use those credentials here.

Once you've set this up on both your old and new computers, you will be able to see what software you had installed on the old computer from the new one and install the pieces you're interested in.

Comment: This won't avoid the need to redownload all the packages, although it's probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nitstorms way will make copies from the already downloaded apps on machine 1 for installing an a second PC. James way will work to but it will essentially redownload all app you select from one machine directly to the new pc from software center.