# Synchronized two tsystem using Ubuntu one

Tags: sync, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy my software to another computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89893/how-to-copy-my-software-to-another-computer)

I had download many applications and installed in my laptop, without repeating same procedure on my desktop is to lengthy, is it is possible to apply same changes using backup or Ubuntu one

Comment: Ubuntu One is not for what you think, it's an Online Storage Service and a Online Music Store, Ubuntu One is not a backup tool in the sense like it isn't like Dejadup.